# What good Feed API (Javascript or exposed via web services) are there?

Tags: c#, mootools, google-feed-api

I've just starting out developing using Feeds, and have so far used Google Feed API to get RSS feeds into my web application.

I was wondering what other types of feed api are available for free consumption.

Also if you have any great feeds you would recommend (available through RSS or otherwise - including custom feeds), please let me know.

I am using MooTools for most of my front end development and .NET/C#/WCF services for the backend, but am not tied to these technologies.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that Google recently released their [Data Protocol APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/)? I've only watched the video on that page so far, but it looks like you'll be able to get, edit and post feeds to your google accounts :)